# Should I use registerDataFrameAsTable in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

During migration from PySpark to Spark with Scala I encountered a problem caused by the fact that SqlContext's [registerDataFrameAsTable method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L669) is private. It made me think that my approach might be incorrect. In PySpark I do the following: load each table: `df = sqlContext.load(source, url, dbtable)`, then register each `sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, dbtable)`, finally using `sqlContext.sql` method I can do my queries (which is basically what I need).

Is it right way to do it? How can I achieve it in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala the `registerTempTable` and `saveAsTable` (which is experimental) methods are available directly on the DataFrame object and should be used.